# Somar valores presentes em uma List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Irei explicar o que quero fazer.
Tenho esta `List`:

```
public static List<Cliente> Clientes = new List<Cliente>();

public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<ProdutoComprado> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class ProdutoComprado
{
    public string NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public string ValorProduto { get; set; }
}
```

Como podem ver, cada cliente tem seus produtos. O que estou precisando é somar os valores da constante **ValorProduto** de todos os produtos de determinado cliente. Creio que para fazer isso terei que usar `Sum` para somar as variáveis. Estava tentando algo como:

```
Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

int total = 0;
foreach (var s in cliente.Produtos)
{
    total = s.ValorProduto.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
}

string soma = string.Format("\n\n\nValor total: {0}", total);
```

Isso não está funcionando. Estou tendo como saída o valor 317.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente alterar o código para o seguinte:

```
Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

int total = cliente.Produtos.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ValorProduto));

string soma = string.Format("\n\n\nValor total: {0}", total);
```

O Sum do LINQ atua percorrendo e somando os elementos da lista, deste modo, o foreach externo é desnecessário. Outro ponto que está falho no seu código é que você está sempre sobrescrevendo o total e não o incrementando (trocando o = por +=).

Comment: haha' eu sabia que alguém perguntaria isso. Eu particularmente gosto de usar string para armazenar valores, independentemente do tipo. Quando preciso realizar alguma operação com determinado valor, me utilizo da conversão do mesmo. Nesse meu caso, converto a string para int com o Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: @user17636 Tudo bem quanto a sua preferência pessoal, mas quando se trabalha em time, sugiro que você repense a respeito disto. Essa atitude é bem insegura e não consigo imaginar um bom motivo para defendê-la. Imagine quantos problemas de conversão você pode ter... as linguagens possuem vários tipos por uma razão. Mas quanto à pergunta original, funcionou?

Comment: Não funcionou, não estou recebendo o valor esperado.

Comment: @user17636 Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, grande abraço! :)

Comment: @user17636 Você é bem vindo, já que funcionou, vou alterar a resposta para explicar o por quê.

Comment: Mais uma gota de conhecimento adicionada ao meu acervo. Obrigado!